# @Query: How to Build complete SQL manually? (Spring JPA)

Tags: sql, spring, string, jpa, jpql

I wan to build my sql statement manually with Java and then provide a final string to my repository like this:

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>{

@Query("?1") 
List<Event> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql); 
    
}
```

This doesn´t work because it is not according to syntax...it says : `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ?`

But how to achive what I intent to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the repository is suppose to take in parameters and those parameters are escaped to prevent SQL injection. I believe the same happening when you are passing an SQL query instead of parameters, the query is being escaped hence rendering it as invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `@Query` annotation.

First, we have to create a custom interface that declares our custom method:

```java
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    List<Event> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql);
}

public interface EventRepositoryCustom {
    List<Event> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql);
}
```

Next, we'll provide our implementation of the `EventRepository` interface:

```java
@Repository
public class EventRepositoryImpl implements EventRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Event> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Event.class);
        // You can use alternative query method instead of native query.
        List<Event> resultList = (List<Event>) query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, another possibility that allows you to do pretty much anything is by using the [`Specification`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) API. It allows you to create programmatically instead of a direct sql statement.

Comment: Instead of constructor initialisation (Which is equivalent to @Autowired), Use `@PersistenceContext` annotation to initialize the `EntityManager`.

Comment: Yes, more correct usage, I updated the example.

Comment: Does that support my sql statement style of jpa where I access the properties directly? or have I to write a real native query?

Comment: You can use jpql (`.createQuery(..)`) or named query (`.createNamedQuery(..)`) if you want, you are in control for this method.

Comment: I didn´t understand why an interface is nessesary here. I just implemented what you posted above without an interface.

Comment: If you are working with repository, it may be more correct in principle to include it in this process. Yes, you can do it separately.